# Reset emacs package manager

Tags: emacs

As a result of random manipulations, I can no longer access the melpa or gnu packages. package-refresh-contents fail to connect.

> (describe-variable 'package-archives) ]  package-archives is a
>   variable defined in ‘package.el’.  Its value is (("gnu" .
>   "https://elpa.gnu.org/packages/")  ("melpa" .
>   "https://melpa.org/packages/"))

The emacs package manager works fine if I log in under another account.
Is it possible, staying under my usual account to reset the package manager ?

Answer (score 1):

The problem was not with the package-archive but with the url-cookie-file that was corrupted, for reasons I do not know.
Resetting url-cookie solved the problem.